# CakePHP auth session vs. cookie not updating

Tags: session, cakephp, cookies, authentication

I have a ACL+auth driven app. Everything works fine but I discovered that user is logged out after a random period of time. After doing some research I discovered that the cookie set once doesn't change it's expiration date on page refresh. So it goes like this:

I set up manually expiration time to 1 minute (Security.level low (with some changes in cake/libs) and timeout 60)

19:00:00 - user loads the page - cookie is set up

19:00:05 - user logs in (cookie doesn't change the expiration date)

19:00:30 - page refresh (cookie doesn't change the expiration date)

19:00:55 - page refresh (cookie doesn't change the expiration date)

19:01:05 - page refresh - user is logged out... (cookie expired after 1 minute)

So the problem is the user gets logged out after 60 seconds from setting a cookie in instead of 60 seconds of inactivity. Does CakePHP deal with cookie files automatically? Or do I have to take care about it myself? 
All I did is set up a cookie name in config/core.php and setup auth. I don't have any cookie handling function, but the cookie is created itself - correctly, just isn't updated

Comment: "with some changes in cake/libs"?! I'd say all bets are off then. What exactly did you change and why? There should be no need to touch the `/cake` directory unless you're fixing a bug in the core.

Comment: Does your server have the suhosin patch?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and countered it with the following code which is called on every page load and ajax call.

```
    if(isset($_COOKIE[Configure::read("Session.cookie")])){
            $session_delay = Configure::read("Session.timeout") * (Configure::read("Security.level") == "low" ? 1800 : 100);
            setcookie(Configure::read("Session.cookie"), $_COOKIE[Configure::read("Session.cookie")], mktime() + $session_delay, "/");
    }
```

Comment: I am considering this solution. But am also considering just setting the expiration of the cookie to be 10 years in the future.